# use another column to save data mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple mysql table that has:

```
ID   type  price
```

The table kind of looks like this: (the userID is the assigned ID of the user logged in (AUTH))

```
ID  type    price
1   Area    8.95
2   Areas   17.9
3   Areas   26.85
4   Areas   35.8
5   Areas   39.95
```

I am using the ID for the value of the type in a select drop-down:price

```
<select name="rooms" id="Areas">
    <option value="" selected="selected">0</option>
    @foreach ($room as $rooms)
    <option data-price="{{ $rooms->price }}" value='{{ $rooms->ID  }}'>{{ $rooms->ID  }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

The reason why I have it like this is due to my js(it updates pricing information based on selection)

When the information is saved to the database it's pulling the value which in the case is the ID.

**Format of table being saved to**

```
ID  USERID  service      price
149 1       1       
150 1       2   
151 1       3   
152 1       4
```

I would like it to pull the column price and type over to price and service so it will look like:

```
ID  USERID  service      price
149 1       Area       8.95    
150 1       Areas      17.9
151 1       Areas      26.85
152 1       Areas      35.8
```

How can this be accomplished? using JOINs?

**Relevant PHP**

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

$input = [
    Input::get('rooms'),
    Input::get('pr_deodorizer'),
    Input::get('pr_protectant') .
    Input::get('pr_sanitizer'),
    Input::get('fr_couch'),
    Input::get('fr_chair'),
    Input::get('fr_sectional'),
    Input::get('fr_ottoman'),
    Input::get('pr_tile'),
    Input::get('pr_hardwood')
];
// echo '<pre>';
// var_dump($input); die;

foreach ($input as $services) {
    $service = new Service();

    $service->userID = $user->id;
    $service->services = $services;

    $service->save();
}
return Redirect::to('book/schedule');
```

Comment: I can't understand what you're saying. First you say the table has 4 columns, but then you show sample contents and say that `userID` is actually in another table. Then you show the format of the table being saved to -- is that the "other table" you were talking about? Why does it have some of the same information as the first table? And is `service` supposed to be a number or string? Why is it sometimes `Area` and sometimes `Areas`, where does that come from?

Comment: Provide some php code which gathers that data in your question so we can assist and answer to it. These are just pure cosmetics ;)

Comment: I provided the php code. Sorry I thought this was explained well. I edited my question a little bit to hopefully clarify the issue I am having. Basically when the value get's saved to the data base I want to use another column that's based on the value to save to another table

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT ID,userID,type,price
FROM rooms
INNER JOIN users ON (rooms.ID=users.ID)
```